# Python: How to find sequences of readings with same id and calculating the interval between first and the last element for every such sequence

Tags: python, sequence

I am working with GPS data to discover personally meaningful places from the track. Once you have clustered the data and assigned each point to a cluster you would get the output file where among other columns there is column for timestamp and cluster id. To determine how long a person has stayed in each cluster every time he/she visited it, you have to sort the data by timestamp and find the sequences of readings all from the same cluster. Say I have an id pattern 1,1,1,2,3,4,4,1,1,2,1,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1 and that is already sorted by timestamp - here you can see a person visited cluster 1 four times. What I would like to know is how to calculate how long the person stayed in cluster 1 every time he/she visited it. The result could be a dictionary where cluster id is key that is followed by values representing time spent for every visitation and the input for the code could be 2D list where every element consist subject data [timestamp, Lat, Lon, cluster_id].

Example from data (time is epoch time in seconds):
time   | cluster
1377997076     |       1
1378000582     |       1
1378000596     |       1
1378031297     |       2
1378031302     |       2
1378031303     |       1
1378031345     |       1
1378033452     |       2
1378034222     |       2

That could also be presented as 2d list: mylist=[[1377997076,1],[1378000582,1],[1378000596,1],[1378031297,2],[1378031302,2],[1378031303,1],[1378031345,1],[1378033452,2],[1378034222,1]]

Comment: Kaisu, is it possible to give a minimal set of code that you are using. People are more likely to help if they see some example data (say a few of these id patterns) that they can play with. Try to explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bit of code to start with:

```
def chunk_sequences(it, n):
    """
    Yield all sequences of n from iterable.
    """
    chunk = []
    for x in it:
        if x == n:
            chunk.append(n)
        else:
            if len(chunk) > 0:
                yield chunk
                chunk = []
    if len(chunk) > 0:
        #needed in case the last sequence runs into the last element
        yield chunk
```

Quick and dirty, if performance is critical you may want to turn to an itertools-based solution (likely involving `takewhile`).

So with the above, you could do:

```
list(chunk_sequences(pattern,1))
Out[59]: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Which could easily become:

```
[len(x) for x in list(chunk_sequences(pattern,1))]
Out[60]: [3, 2, 1, 5]
```

..which are the lengths of each respective stay in cluster 1.